# Is there a way to rbind files without it needing to convert from numeric to character in R?

Tags: r, type-conversion, bind, rbind

I am trying to read and combine 80+ excel files in the .xlsx format into one database using the code below:

```
library(readxl)
library(purr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
alldata <- file.list %>%
map_dfr(read_excel) %>%
reduce(bind_rows)
```

The issue I have is it comes up with `Error: Column 'Cage' can't be converted from numeric to character`.  When I had this problem for other columns, I just needed to remove any accidental non-numeric characters from the column. However, I cannot do this for this column, as I need the columns to contain forward slashes at times. Can anybody help me avoid this issue?

Note: this error comes up regardless of whether I use `reduce(rbind_list)`, `reduce(rbind.fill)`, or `reduce(rbind)`

Comment: You should consider using a conditional statement such as if() paired with a regex matching statement to identify if a slash exists - if it does then trim the column name

Comment: are you able to provide an min example of the problematic data?

Comment: you could try lapply-ing an as.character for all the individual excel files and relevant columns before you bind them together, thus ensuring that their column types match

Answer (score 0):

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

alldata <- file.list %>%
     map_dfr(~read_excel(.x) %>% 
                mutate_all(as.character))
```

Guess your probably done with this, but can see this issue stumping others. You can solve it by adding `%>% mutate_all(as.character)` to standardise every column in the `read_excel` function.